# The term "synchronous" in Java concurrent programming has anything to do with synchronization in synchronous/asynchronous?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency

1. Concurrent, parallel, serial.
2. Synchronous, asynchronous.
3. Thread synchronization.

Are there any relationships between these terms?

Hope someone can answer me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a connection between 1 and 2.

- Concurrent and parallel processing often involves asynchronous modes of communication.
- Synchronous modes of communication imply that the callee and caller operate serially

There is a tenuous connection between 1 and 3.

- You can implement concurrency or parallelism using threads and threads that operate on shared state need appropriate synchronization.

There is an even more tenuous connection between 2 and 3.

- If you implement any communication (synchronous or asynchronous) between threads, then it is *likely* to involve some form of thread synchronization.  (But not always, and not necessarily using a `synchronized` method or block.)

---

But I don't think this is likely to help you understand the respective terms.  I think you are better off reading more broadly ... and deeply ... on the respective concepts.  The connections between them are not very enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

Usually parallel tasks need to interact: start one after another, or pass computed value from one task to another task.

Interaction can be of 2 kinds: synchronous and asynchronous. Synchronous interaction assumes that one or both interacting threads are suspended, until the expected condition is met, like in `Future.get()` or `BlockingQueue.take()`.

Asynchronous interaction usually is implemented as a (callback) method call which signals that the condition is met. The acceptor of the signal decides what to do: start new task, resume a thread, or just remember the signal. Example is `CompletableFuture.whenComplete(BiConsumer)`.

Both synchronous and asynchronous interactions are implemented by thread synchronization.